# Clickonce Deployed WPF Desktop App Crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, clickonce

I have deployed a WPF Windows desktop app that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1. Over a dozen users have installed it on their Win 10 PC's and the app installs and runs without issue. The app is signed with a code-signing certificate which is working fine. There is no unmanaged code in the app.

On one Win 10 PC the app installs without error and even starts (displays sign-in screen) without error. But as soon as the user signs-in, when the main window is about to open, the app crashes and disappears from the screen.

I've managed to copy the following error message, and I have the Windows .wer file, but the contents of are not helpful and I can't work out what is causing the error or how to fix it.

```
Faulting application name: samadhi.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5f8d1af0
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4250.0, time stamp: 0x5f2a0630
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0010409c
Faulting process id: 0xb40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a8fc436df911
Faulting application path: C:\Users\mongk\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\DQL38KV8.XQ5\ZK547QA9.7LW\sama..tion_ee5134a9f21f5a9c_0001.0000_5a8f16833951b6e5\samadhi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 3aca7880-67c2-44f3-9943-074e5e522d56
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Application: samadhi.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 7270409C (72600000) with exit code 80131506.
```

Error message says: "**The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime**". However, I've tried the following, but none of these actions have fixed the problem:

- re-installed .NET Framework
- ran .NET repair
- cleared .NET cache
- reinstalled the app
- checked Windows is up-to-date

Comment: this basically says nothing, use ur app log to check what's wrong, or if none is available , try and install vs on the user machine and debug

Comment: Add global event handlers. Google for example code. There are 4 or 5 handlers to hook. In there, log your error details. And add logging generally. I like nlog but if your app is widely distributed you might want to consider free level ms app insights. You want a stack trace from the inner most exception.

Comment: @styx my app has an error logging - but there is no exception. the app simply crashes. unfortunately installing VS on the client PC is not an option.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm now running into the same problem :| It's frustrating that there's no error/exception message or stack trace. There's just nothing to go on :(

Comment: @Clonkex I never determined what the cause of this error was. However, seeing that my app was working on many other computers I advised my client to have his PC checked and/or Windows fixed or re-installed. He ended up getting another PC and my app worked fine on this one.

Comment: In my case it turned out to be related to using CefSharp. It requires a .exe file to be included but my clickonce deployment was leaving that file out (presumably for security reasons?) and for whatever reason that caused the app to silently crash. I ended up fixing it by manually specifying that the file be included.